# Javascript blur with password input not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
    var passwordTextBox = angular.element("#password");
    passwordTextBox.blur(function() {

       //do smth.
    });

 <input type="password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="Password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
```

And blur is not fired when I click outside password box, but is fired if I start to type into another box.

And this code has no issues if input type is text.

Why is this happening ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Angular is not jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely doing it wrong. First off, let any time you are doing DOM manipulation behind the scenes be a red-flag. Directives should be the only thing that do that and, for the most part, angular has most that you will need.

That said, angular SUPPORTS blur natively. You just need to bind it to a controller function, like so:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" data-ng-blur="someFunction()" data-ng-model="Password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
```

and in the controller:

```
...
scope.someFunction = function(){
 //do things
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm new to angular and I didn't know angular supports blur natively,and I'm aware that all DOM manipulation should be handled in directives but I'm in a bit of hurry and don't quite get directives,

Comment: Then consider it a general rule that dom manipulation is bad. Look to the angular documentation for help as it will almost certainly yield the answer.